How To Change The Style Of Customer Control Inside Another Custom Control (Using ComponentResourceKey)
Special thanks to @BionicCode for helping me get started.
So I an trying to better understand CustomControl styles. So, I have created a custom toggle button called MyToggleButton, and I want to use it inside another custom control called MyCustomControl.

Here is my code behind for the toggle:
public class MyToggleButton : ToggleButton
{
    public static ComponentResourceKey ButtonBrushKey = 
        new ComponentResourceKey(typeof(MyToggleButton), "ButtonBrush");

    static MyToggleButton()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyToggleButton), 
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyToggleButton)));
    }
}

In the Generic.xaml:
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static ctrl:MyToggleButton.ButtonBrushKey}" Color="Red" />

<Style TargetType="{x:Type ctrl:MyToggleButton}">

    <Setter Property="Background" Value="SteelBlue"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="28"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="65"/>

    <Setter Property="Template">

        <Setter.Value>

            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ctrl:MyToggleButton}">

                <Border x:Name="back" 
                    BorderBrush="{Binding BorderBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                    Background="{Binding Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                    BorderThickness="{Binding BorderThickness, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                    CornerRadius="5">

                    <Grid>

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <!--BUTTON-->
                        <Border x:Name="button" 
                            Grid.Column="0" 
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                            Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static ctrl:MyToggleButton.ButtonBrushKey}}"
                            Width="16" 
                            Height="16" 
                            Margin="2"
                            CornerRadius="3"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left">

                            <Path x:Name="icon" 
                                    Fill="{DynamicResource {x:Static ctrl:MyToggleButton.ButtonBrushKey}}"
                                    Stretch="Uniform"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    Margin="2"
                                    Data="{Binding OnPathData, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>

                        </Border>

                        <!--TEXT-->
                        <TextBlock x:Name="text" 
                                    Grid.Column="1"
                                    Text="On"
                                    FontSize="12"
                                    Foreground="White"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

                    </Grid>

                </Border>

            </ControlTemplate>

        </Setter.Value>

    </Setter>

</Style>

Then, I want to use it in MyCustomControl.
I'm trying to set the ButtonBrush resource on the Toggle from within the MyCustomControl. It has no effect. See the first line here:
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static toggle:MyToggleButton.ButtonBrushKey}" Color="Green" />

<Style TargetType="{x:Type ctrl:MyCustomControl}">

    <Setter Property="Template">

        <Setter.Value>

            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ctrl:MyCustomControl}">

                <Border BorderBrush="SteelBlue"
                        BorderThickness="2"
                        Background="LightGray">

                    <Grid>

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <toggle:MyToggleButton Grid.Column="0"
                                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                Height="45"
                                                Width="100"
                                                Margin="5,0,0,0"/>

                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" 
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    Text="Some Text"
                                    FontWeight="Bold"
                                    Margin="5,0,0,0"/>

                    </Grid>

                </Border>

            </ControlTemplate>

        </Setter.Value>

    </Setter>

</Style>

However, if I put both controls on a window, I can change the toggle button's ButtonBrush there.
<Window.Resources>
    <!--This makes ALL toggle buttons have a yellow inner button-->
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static toggle:MyToggleButton.ButtonBrushKey}" Color="Yellow" />
</Window.Resources>


How can I set the ButtonBrush from inside MyCustomControl?

What do you mean by from within the MyCustomControl? In the fourth code snippet, the SolidColorBrush is outside of a Style for MyCustomControl.

Yes, that's in MyCustomControl. As I said in the comment above it, setting

has no effect.However, it does work in the Window.
BTW, I pushed my sample to a public repo here https://github.com/MaroisConsulting/MyCustomControl

What do you mean by that's in MyCustomControl.? Is it in your Style or ControlTemplate for MyCustomControl? As for your repo, I can find neither MyToggleButton nor MyCustomControl.

I will show you a simple example with one element.
I think from it you will understand how you need to reconfigure your Solution.
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace MyCustomControl.Widget
{
    // The key is declared in a separate class.
    // This solution is not mandatory.
    // I did it this way to demonstrate the independence of the key from the element.
    // If it is more convenient for you, you can declare them in one class.
    public static class ExampleComponentResourceKey
    {
        public static ComponentResourceKey SomeBrushKey =
            new ComponentResourceKey(typeof(ExampleComponentResourceKey), nameof(SomeBrushKey)[0..^3]);
    }

    public class SomeControl : Control
    {
        static SomeControl()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(SomeControl),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(SomeControl)));
        }
    }
}

Generic.xaml:
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyCustomControl.Widget">


    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type local:ExampleComponentResourceKey}, ResourceId=SomeBrush}"
                     Color="Red"/>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:SomeControl}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:SomeControl">
                    <Label Margin="20" Background="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type local:ExampleComponentResourceKey}, ResourceId=SomeBrush}}"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

Example #1:
<Window x:Class="MyCustomControl.Demo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:wacky="clr-namespace:MyCustomControl.Widget;assembly=MyCustomControl.Widget"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Wacky Widget Control Demo" 
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        Height="450" 
        Width="800">

    <Window.Resources>

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type wacky:ExampleComponentResourceKey}, ResourceId=SomeBrush}"
                     Color="Green"/>

    </Window.Resources>
    
    <Grid>
        <wacky:SomeControl/>
    </Grid>
</Window>

Result:

Example #2:
<Window x:Class="MyCustomControl.Demo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:wacky="clr-namespace:MyCustomControl.Widget;assembly=MyCustomControl.Widget"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Wacky Widget Control Demo" 
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        Height="450" 
        Width="800">


    <UniformGrid Rows="1">
        <wacky:SomeControl>
            <FrameworkElement.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type wacky:ExampleComponentResourceKey}, ResourceId=SomeBrush}"
                     Color="Green"/>
            </FrameworkElement.Resources>
        </wacky:SomeControl>
        
        <wacky:SomeControl/>

    </UniformGrid>
</Window>

Result:

P.S.

I do not recommend implementing INotifyPropertyChanged in classes derived from Dependency Object, including various UserControl and CustomControl. Instead of CLR properties with INotifyPropertyChanged support, you should use Dependency Property or Attached Property.
I do not recommend using custom classes implementing ICommand in UI elements, similar to your RelayCommand and RelayCommand. Instead, I recommend using RoutedCommand and handling their bubbling. This implementation is more typical for WPF and more flexible for various GUI-level tasks.

        #region Commands
        public static readonly RoutedCommand ClearCommand = new RoutedUICommand("Some Text", nameof(ClearCommand), typeof(WackyWidget));
        public static readonly RoutedCommand SearchCommand = new RoutedUICommand("Some Text", nameof(SearchCommand), typeof(WackyWidget));
        #endregion

        #region CTOR
        static WackyWidget()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(WackyWidget),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(WackyWidget)));

            CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding(
                typeof(WackyWidget),
                new CommandBinding
                (
                    ClearCommand,
                    (source, e) => ((WackyWidget)source).ClearExecuted(),
                    (source, e) => e.CanExecute = ((WackyWidget)source).ClearCanExecute()
                ));

            CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding(
                typeof(WackyWidget),
                new CommandBinding
                (
                    SearchCommand,
                    (source, e) => ((WackyWidget)source).SearchExecuted(),
                    (source, e) => e.CanExecute = ((WackyWidget)source).SearchCanExecute()
                ));
        }

        <Button Grid.Column="1"
                Command="{x:Static local:WackyWidget.SearchCommand}"
                Style="{DynamicResource {x:Static local:WackyWidget.SearchButtonStyleKey}}"/>

        <Button Grid.Column="2"
                Command="{x:Static local:WackyWidget.ClearCommand}"
                Style="{DynamicResource {x:Static local:WackyWidget.ClearButtonStyleKey}}"/>

